# Conditional logging with log4net

Tags: log4net-configuration

I have a program that uses log4Net using both text and smtp appenders.

When the program runs several logging are captured by the smtp appenders and are buffered waiting for the program end before sending mail.

When the program is nearly completed I might discover that I do not need to send emails, and actually I log something like "Nothing to do".

I know that it is possible to manipulate by code the appenders configuration so I could suppress the mail setting the Threshold to off.

I would like to know if it is possible to get the same result using just log4net configuration: the smtp appender should not send an email if a specific string is logged at any time. If instead that string is not logged it should behave normally and send all the lines that match the defined filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR;

- create a custom `ITriggeringEventEvaluator`
- configure your smtp appender with this evaluator: decide what must happen when the buffer is full (discard messages, send them)
- use the auto-flush of your appender to send the log events forward

---

There are two properties in a `BufferingAppenderSkeleton` in log4net that may interest you here. When you configure such an appender to be [`Lossy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.BufferingAppenderSkeleton.Lossy.html), `Evaluator` and `LossyEvaluator` are used to determine if messages should be sent to the next appenders.

The `Evaluator` property lets you define a class inheriting from `ITriggeringEventEvaluator`; when a message is logged and the buffer is full, the evaluator is called and if it returns true on the `IsTriggeringEvent` method the event buffer is processed.
The `LossyEvaluator` works in the same way, except it is called to decide whether the oldest event that will disappear from the buffer because it is full must be logged or not.

Since your `SmtpAppender` is a `BufferingAppenderSkeleton`, you can use the `Evaluator` property in order to define what triggers or not the email being sent (ie a logging event where you say "no log", or whatever)

However if you expect your appender to decide on its own whether or not to send the event logs when it is closed (ie should it auto-flush or not) it is the `LossyEvaluator` that is used.

Now for the bad news: there is only one instance of a `ITriggeringEventEvaluator` implementation in log4net, which evaluates log events based on their level. So you will have to code your own trigger in order to recognize special messages sent to the appender by your application.

Comment: Good idea. But I see it cannot be done on configuration only, we must develop an extension to Log4Net. Maybe it would be simpler to "log" in List<String> and at the end of the program decide if I can discard the log or send all the strings in List to the real log method.

Comment: Yes, lots of people decide against coding some extension to log4net for this kind of problem, but lugging a list of string and pushing it at the end is a bit of a code smell in my opinion: it is possible, perhaps easier at first glance but i don't really like it.

Comment: In fact, when you think about it the buffer appender _is_ a list of data that is kept behind the scenes, so I'd really recommend using it

Comment: I do not like it either, but sometimes time constraints and inexperience with log4net lead to put plugs in the nose :-(

Comment: Anyway I'll try in spare time. You are right: there is already a list, so it is better to use it.

Comment: I know :) What's more this case here is really special since you have to think about many code paths. In your other question (log a message only once) the solution is much clearer since there is only one path for the log to go through. Best of luck regarding this problem.