# Log4Net Backup Appender

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender, log4net-filter

I am running Log4Net in a .NET CORE 3.1 web app.  I have almost everything the way I want it.  There is one thing that is eluding me though.  I have an appender that logs to my SQL Server DB.  If and only if the connection goes down or the DB can't create a row, I want my windows event log appender to kick in and log both that the DB is down AND the event that was going to go to the DB.  I can think of some hacky ways to do this, but I'm looking for the most elegant / robust solution possible.  I imagine this is a pretty common scenario, but I couldn't find any help on the internet.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: Conditional logging - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894103/conditional-logging-with-log4net

Comment: @Oxymoron conditional logging seems to be what I need.  Please respond as an answer and I will give you credit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional logging with log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894103/conditional-logging-with-log4net)

Comment: @Oxymoron, I ended up creating a named instance of a special logger, then called it when the ADONETAPPENDER errored out.  Conditional logging works too.  If you post this as an answer, as opposed to a comment, I will give you credit.